# two points on a unit sphere

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Consider the two vectors to the points on the unit sphere,
$${\bf v}_i=(\sin\theta_i\cos\varphi_i,\sin\theta_i\sin\varphi_i,\cos\theta_i)$$
with $i=1,2$. Use the dot product to get the angle $\psi$ between them:
$${\bf v}_1\cdot {\bf v}_2=\left(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\left(\varphi_1-\varphi_2\right)\right)=\cos\psi.$$

Then the arclength is
$$s=\psi=\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\left(\varphi_1-\varphi_2\right)\right).$$
My question is: can I find the shortest distance between these two points on the sphere by minimizing the length?

Comment: The arclength you found is minimal distance between two points on a sphere in terms of other arclengths that connect same points. If you want to vary angles to find which arclength is shortest, then you don't have to differentiate or anything like that. Obviously it's 0 when $\theta_1 = \theta_2$ and $\phi_1=\phi_2$.

Comment: actually I want to calculate shortest distance between 2 points on a sphere by joining curves passing thorugh them with lenghth given by the formulae $l_{\gamma}(S^2)=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(d\phi/dt)^2+ \sin^2\phi (d\theta/dt)^2}dt$