# How to minimize the length of a curve on $S^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates

The length of a curve  $\gamma$ starting from a point $p$ and ending at another point $q$  on $S^2$ is given by the formula $$l_{\gamma}(S^2)=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(d\phi/dt)^2+ \sin^2\phi (d\theta/dt)^2}dt$$
I want to minimize the distance using calculus. How do we do that? What do we differentiate with respect to and equate to $0$? I am not able to start.

Comment: This is (at least) the fourth question you're asking in swift succession about the distance between two points on a sphere ([first](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327679), [second](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328387), [third](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329271)). At the very least, you should link them to each other to avoid duplication of efforts. Even better would be to give some thought to how they're related and how you could get at what you're after in fewer questions.

Comment: @joriki I have done in completely different way and now I have understood completely, so I can delet all these three as my little poor brain has no capacity to understand any one of those answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider a vectorfield $v$ defined on the points of $\gamma$, tangent to the sphere, orthogonal to the curve and zero on the two extremes of the curve. Then consider the variation of your curve $\gamma$:
$$
  \gamma_h (t) = \gamma(t) + h v 
$$
Then write your functional $\ell_{\gamma_h}$ and compute the derivative with respect to $h$ for $h=0$. Then you let this derivative be equal to $0$ for all $v$.

Comment: please please be more explicit, I am not able to understand anything!

Comment: This is a difficult task, you should explain what are your knowleges. Are you studying for some course?

Comment: This is the second time he asks this question, and it is a really hard task to try to help him.